# How to group C# class object values. Is this possible with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have been experimenting with grouping object fields and can't seem to get this working.

Here is the class object

```
  public class Inventory
    {
        public string warehouse_id { get; set; }
        public string product_id { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
    }


     public List<Inventory> inventories { get; set; }
```

The data is coming in via JSON from an API call as such:

```
{
"inventories": [{
    "warehouse_id": "warehouse1",
    "product_id": "productA",
    "quantity": 5400
}, {
    "warehouse_id": "warehouse2",
    "product_id": "productA",
    "quantity": 571
}, {
    "warehouse_id": "warehouse3",
    "product_id": "productA",
    "quantity": 0
}, {
    "warehouse_id": "warehouse1",
    "product_id": "prod_B",
    "quantity": 0
}, {
    "warehouse_id": "warehouse2",
    "product_id": "prod_B",
    "quantity": 0
}, {
    "warehouse_id": "warehouse3",
    "product_id": "prod_B",
    "quantity": 1
},
```

]
}

No problems deserializing the object.

```
Request request = new Request("api/path/to/get/inventory/data", Method.GET);
var r= request.Execute<InventoryReport>();
```

Now I have a populated InventoryReport object.

What I need is to ignore the warehouse_id value and group the quantity data by product.
EX. `"inventories": [{
        "warehouse_id":"any value here",
        "product_id": "productA",
        "quantity": 5571 // Here we have grouped the total quantity by product
    },`

The question is in two parts.  Is it possible to get this result with LINQ?  I tried this but it does not work (I am thinking because of the variable warehouse_ids.)

```
 var groupedInventory = from newObject1 in r.inventories
            group arrayObject1 by new { newObject1.quantity, newObject1.product_id }
            into g
            select new { KKey = g.Key, Obj = g };
```

If not possible, what is the best way to approach this.  I'm just not getting it so any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var groupedInventory = from obj in r.inventories
                       group obj by obj.product_id into g
                       select new Inventory() { product_id = g.Key, quantity = g.Sum(e => e.quantity) };
```

I think it is pretty self-explanatory. If you have questions, leave a comment.

Comment: Yes, very clear (and working) answer.  Thank you for your help.